# Printing a selected number from lines stored in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write something that takes input such as

```
4 
2 11 1
3 2 1 1
4 4 5 6 2
5 1 1 1 1 2
```

The first number indicates how many lines follow, the first numbers of each line indicate the amount of following integers, and the last number of each line indicates what would be printed (index starting at 1). The numbers in between are what is stored in the array:

```
11
2
5
1
```

This is what I've come up with so far, which is obviously wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int lines = sc.nextInt();
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[size - 1];

    while (lines <= 0) {
        lines = sc.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= lines; i++) {
        a[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

I don't want answers; I want some guidance, because I'm lost.

Comment: what happened to the last line? 5  1 1 1 1 2

Comment: What do you mean by "the last indicates what would be printed"? Is the last number on each row not also stored in the matrix?

Comment: Why are you editing your question to remove the details of it? You should leave the question so that if others have a similar problem this question can be used as a resource.

Comment: Your second nextInt() must be already inside the lines loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the ultimate goal is to create an `int[][]`, though notably it may be a jagged matrix (different rows may have different lengths).

If you keep this in mind, what to do with each piece of input becomes simpler.

From there you want to print the `(i - 1)th` element of each array, based off the last element of each row. This is simple once you have your matrix, if a bit weird.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


    int lines = sc.nextInt();
    int[][] input = new Integer[lines][]; //This is the matrix we are building

    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){       //For each row of numbers
        int size = sc.nextInt();          //Find out how many numbers on this row
        input[i] = new int[size];         //Create array of this size for this row
        for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){    //For each number on this row
            input[i][x] = sc.nextInt();   //Read it into the correct row,col positon
        }
    }

    sc.close();

    //Do printing
    for(int[] row : input){
        int lastElm = row[row.length - 1];
        System.out.println(row[lastElm - 1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following:

1. Split document in lines, save those as strings
2. ignore line 1, maybe you could use it to crosscheck the total ammount of lines?
3. Use .split("\s+") on the lines, then cast the results to integers
4. take the last number out of each line(let's call the number i), then get the ith element of the array

Does this make any sense? One question i have is, does the input file have linebreaks or is it a continous stream of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

You might just do the following:

- First, read the first line:

  ```
  int numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
  ```
- Then create a `for` loop with the given integer in order to loop over the following lines:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) { ... }
  ```
- Then, within the `for` loop, take each line:

  ```
  String line = sc.nextLine();
  ```
- Then, split the line into parts, with a space as delimiter:

  ```
  String[] parts = line.split(" ");
  ```

  The last index of the `parts` array must be printed.

  ```
  int index = parts[parts.length - 1];
  int numberToPrint = parts[index];
  System.out.println(numberToPrint);
  ```

As you can see, you don't need the first element to check the length of the given sequence of numbers. If you split the line by a space, you can just call the last element using the array property `length`.

PS: If the user input is malformed, probably an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown. You can just catch it and accuse the user for being stupid.